# Analysis to be done on the dataa

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a data with all the instances when Phone Numbers had the data session for 9 months, So if a phone no had multiple sessions in a day i have all of them in Separate rows.

I need to find no. of days when a particular no. had a session on monthly basis.?

Comment: Have you tried using a Pivot Table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a countifs formula in excel 2010, assuming I understand the problem correctly.

```
=COUNTIFS([column of phonenumbers],[Phonenumnber to match],[Date Column],">="&[Startdate of the month],[Date Column],"<"&[Startdate of the next month])
```

That will return a count of all the calls from a specific phone number during that month.